# 0xDBE / PHPStorm / IDEA fails to synchronize database's tables

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, datagrip

I'm getting the following error when trying to sync the database tables in 0xDBE:

```
Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array.free() is not yet implemented.
Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array.free() is not yet implemented.
The SQL statement:
with languages as (select oid as lang_oid, lanname as lang
                   from pg_catalog.pg_language),
     routines as (select proname as r_name,
                         prolang as lang_oid,
                         oid as r_id,
                         xmin as r_state_number,
                         proargnames as arg_names,
                         proargmodes as arg_modes,
                         proargtypes::int[] as in_arg_types,
                         proallargtypes::int[] as all_arg_types,
                         proargdefaults as arg_defaults,
                         provariadic as arg_variadic_id,
                         prorettype as ret_type_id,
                         proisagg as is_aggregate,
                         proiswindow as is_window,
                         provolatile as volatile_kind
                  from pg_catalog.pg_proc
                  where pronamespace = oid(?)
                    and xmin::varchar::bigint > ?)
select *
from routines natural join languages

  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.BaseExceptionRecognizer.recognizeException(BaseExceptionRecognizer.java:48)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.JdbcIntermediateSession.recognizeException(JdbcIntermediateSession.java:347)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.JdbcIntermediateCursor.fetch(JdbcIntermediateCursor.java:249)
  at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.impl.RemoteCursorImpl.fetch(RemoteCursorImpl.java:31)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
  at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
  at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
  at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:171)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.fetch(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:124)
  at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$100(RemoteUtil.java:36)
  at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:229)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.fetch(Unknown Source)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.intermediate.AdaptIntermediateStructCollectingCursor.fetch(AdaptIntermediateStructCollectingCursor.java:107)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.core.BaseQueryRunner.fetchPack(BaseQueryRunner.java:88)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.core.BaseQueryRunner.run(BaseQueryRunner.java:70)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector$SchemaRetriever.h(PostgreIntrospector.java:459)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector$SchemaRetriever.access$600(PostgreIntrospector.java:177)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector$SchemaRetriever$4.run(PostgreIntrospector.java:246)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector$SchemaRetriever.a(PostgreIntrospector.java:203)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector$SchemaRetriever.retrieve(PostgreIntrospector.java:242)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector$2.run(PostgreIntrospector.java:169)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.core.BaseSession.inTransaction(BaseSession.java:88)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.core.BaseFacade$2.run(BaseFacade.java:93)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.core.BaseFacade.inSession(BaseFacade.java:125)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.core.BaseFacade.inTransaction(BaseFacade.java:89)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector.a(PostgreIntrospector.java:165)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector.b(PostgreIntrospector.java:153)
  at com.intellij.dbm.postgre.PostgreIntrospector.introspect(PostgreIntrospector.java:86)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.NativeSchemaLoader.a(NativeSchemaLoader.java:113)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.NativeSchemaLoader.introspectAndAdapt(NativeSchemaLoader.java:67)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseSchemaLoader.loadDataSourceState(DatabaseSchemaLoader.java:107)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AbstractDataSource.refreshMetaData(AbstractDataSource.java:59)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AbstractDataSource$1.perform(AbstractDataSource.java:34)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AbstractDataSource$1.perform(AbstractDataSource.java:32)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AbstractDataSource.performJdbcOperation(AbstractDataSource.java:110)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AbstractDataSource.refreshMetaData(AbstractDataSource.java:32)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceUiUtil$2.run(DataSourceUiUtil.java:167)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
  at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:367)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array.free() is not yet implemented.
  at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:727)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array.free(Jdbc4Array.java:57)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.JdbcValueGetters$AbstractArrayGetter.getValue(JdbcValueGetters.java:473)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.JdbcRowFetchers$TupleFetcher.fetchRow(JdbcRowFetchers.java:163)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.JdbcRowFetchers$TupleFetcher.fetchRow(JdbcRowFetchers.java:145)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.JdbcRowsCollectors$ListCollector.collectRows(JdbcRowsCollectors.java:211)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.JdbcRowsCollectors$ListCollector.collectRows(JdbcRowsCollectors.java:198)
  at org.jetbrains.jdba.jdbc.JdbcIntermediateCursor.fetch(JdbcIntermediateCursor.java:245)
  at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.impl.RemoteCursorImpl.fetch(RemoteCursorImpl.java:31)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, when executing queries from the console, the data I get is the correct. I'm not very sure what's failing here, as I don't have any problems when using pgAdmin.

Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I solved the issue by re-downloading the JDBC driver 0xDBE was using. Right-Click on the Data Source, then go to preferences and erase the driver files currently being used and download them again.

[image: JDBC files]
[image: Download JDBC files]

You have to restart IDE after redownloading the driver for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I had the same problem within IntelliJ IDEA and this solution worked for me.  I had to restart IDEA after downloading the new driver.

Comment: that error is gone, but for some reason 0xDBE is treating one of my databases as read-only when it isn't, and I haven't checked read-only. See issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709655/0xdbe-cannot-apply-changes-this-table-is-read-only-cell-editor-changes-cannot-b -- incredibly frustrating

Comment: Required restart afterwards and then worked like a charm on 0xDBE Natasha 1.0 Preview

Comment: Same issue but above solution not working for SQL Server datasource.

Comment: Solved it for me too in Intellij Idea. Started happening after upgrading to version 15.

Comment: Same issue too, but for me the fix is not working... Using IntelliJ ultimate with PostgreSQL database.

Comment: This solution works for me to fix the same error in RubyMine.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to fix this issue by opening the data source settings page (where you enter the DB credentials) and switching to tab `Options` and enabling `Introspect using JDBC metadata`:

[image]