# datagrip Cannot apply changes This table is read only. Cell editor changes cannot be applied

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

So simply the problem occurs when I want to edit selected rows and then apply it. I'm sure it worked some time ago. Tried redownload postgres driver in preferences(yeah, I use postgres) Anyone faced same issue? Anyone succeed?

PS. Running on 142.4861.1.

I found read only checkbox in connection preferences, it was not set, toggling didn't help, upgrading, reseting also didn't help.

Comment: What actually helped was toggling Auto-commit checkbox in console, after that everything runs flawlessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What actually helped was toggling Auto-commit checkbox in console, after that everything runs flawlessly.

Comment: glad to hear i'm not the only person with this problem

Comment: so frustrating. I'm still stuck with this, none of these proposed fixes have worked

Comment: Please check in your connection settings whether read-only checkbox isn't  toggled on?

Comment: Restarting the application is what fixed it for me. No change required.

Answer (score 6):

Try synchronize database connection. It helped me in mysql connection.

Comment: This worked for me. What's going on here, why did it work?

Answer (score 6):

In my case in version `2020.1` of DataGrip (SQL was run from the opened file, on unique table, so that select just worked as expected, but when I was trying to edit - error appeared: `unresolved table reference`): specifying schemes in request helped. So that `SELECT * FROM users;` was changed to `SELECT * FROM schemadb.users;` and that helped. Probably there is a bug. I've tried all the methods mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. I would add that you could also simply synchronize schema anew (if you defined schema scope in Data Source properties under the Schemas tab). That did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

If your query is using field alias (renaming column instead of using actual column name) , then Datagrip set data results as read only.

**Solution:**
Rewrite query using field names as in the table and rerun query.  Then you will be able to edit the rows.

**Example**

Rewrite this:

```
select id,interest_recalcualated_on, interest_recalculation_enabled alias from m_loan;
```

..to this:

```
select id,interest_recalcualated_on, interest_recalculation_enabled from m_loan;
```

Comment: This is simply not user's fault. it is up to datagrip to improve it. SQLyog is even flawless doing it in earlier version.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that actually worked for me, after trying everything above multiple times, was deleting each DB connection and remaking a new one from scratch.

Comment: Yes, only this thing worked out! Thank you. What a shameful bug for BrainStorm's datagrip team.

Answer (score 2):

This can be due to default settings, make it sure your your **transaction Mode** settings are as below

[image]

Comment: I had to change the transaction mode in the properties of the database from "auto" to "manual".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with datagrop `2020.2`. I have followed all the method but for me, just delete the connection and create new connection (never trying to duplicate) just manual. It is works!

Comment: **Connection > Properties > Options > Transaction control -> Manual** solved issue for me

Answer (score 2):

seems like DataGrip doesn't allow to change data in the ui table if you select specific columns with joins.

so if you `select table1.column1, table2.column2 from <table1> inner join <table2>` and try to change the value in column1, you will receive `This table is read only` warning

only if you do `select * from <table>`, you can edit the cell values

Answer (score 1):

Set and clear Read-only in Data Source Properties helps me.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was removing a field alias - going from this:

```
SELECT
  l.MSKU Item_SKU,
  l.Supplier,
  l.ASIN,
  l.title,
  l.Buy_Price
FROM listings l
WHERE l.Buy_Price IS NULL
ORDER BY l.Supplier, l.listingID desc;
```

to this:

```
   SELECT
  l.MSKU,
  l.Supplier,
  l.ASIN,
  l.title,
  l.Buy_Price
FROM listings l
WHERE l.Buy_Price IS NULL
ORDER BY l.Supplier, l.listingID desc;
```

is all it took for me to be able to edit the results of the query

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked. I had to update DataGrip from 2017.2 to 2018.3

I had to open the project by navigating to: /home/user/.DataGrip2017.2/config/projects/my_project/

All my scripts for this project as I did not want to import the config from the old version of Datagrip. So I'll probably need to downgrade, get the scripts and upgrade again.

Answer (score 0):

I struck the same issue, not Postgres but MySql, PhpStorm 2019.1 when I had two schema available on the same db connection and my query: `select * from users where full_name like '%handy%';` resulted in a result table that couldn't be edited even though the console reported it was querying the `stage` schema. A more specific query: `select * from stage.users where full_name like '%handy%';` using the exact table name led to a results table that could be inline edited.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get around this issue was to remove the database connection details for the given connection and recreate them from scratch. While this was happening to me on this specific connection, editing was working fine on other connections, which suggests the problem might be related to specific parameters around the connection in question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I changed back my Select query to * (wild char to select all the columns), from specific columns, the edit and save started to working again. This is strange! May be worth reporting a bug to intellij. I'm using DataGrip 2020.1 on macOs Catalina 10.15.3

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same problem but just realized I needed to submit changes (with a button or command + enter) for them to be applied.

This answer is 4 years late though. Maybe the bug was already fixed haha, but this may help someone else.

Comment: I cannot even edit the cell without this error popping up. Version 2022.1.2

Answer (score -1):

try this

1. In the IDE settings (Ctrl+Alt+S), go to Database | General.
2. Select the Open results in new tab checkbox and click OK.
3. Re-run your query, and you'll be able to edit and commit the changes in the new tabs.

Answer (score -3):

The problem for me was the obvious (well obvious after identifying it) - using a MySQL keyword as a field name (yes I know its not a good idea but thats how it is sometimes). So this caused the error

```
select id,name,value from mytable;
```

The correct way to write this of course is using backticks so:

```
select id,name,`value` from mytable;
```

and this solved it for me.