# PhpStorm Access to Database

Tags: php, database, phpstorm

I am trying to change values in my database, but I am always getting this error :

```
This table is read-only. Cell editor changes cannot be applied.
```

But it´s not set to this value, I can access it freely with any other php script. Any ideas that might help?

Comment: It's not clear where the issue is. Please show some screenshots that would provide the details.

Comment: The username you supplied for PHPStorm to access your database may be a username with only certain privileges or you may have ticked the "read only" box on your dataSource connection window. Check these.

Comment: try this question for useful hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709655/datagruo-cannot-apply-changes-this-table-is-read-only-cell-editor-changes-canno

Comment: I have only 2 users with permitted usage and that is "phpmyadmin" and "pma". But my connection is with a user over SSH which has all priveleges.

Comment: all privileges on all tables? use this Q&A to check: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/mysql-show-grants-for-all-users . Otherwise check the table allows users to edit it. Error reads as a table privilege issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working. I added my "phpmyadmin" with all the pma tables to my "Schemas" in the Properties in my DB Connection (also mysql and performance_schema) Before that I also synchronized the Connection (right click on the Connection under the database Tab, this didn´t seem to help, but maybe it made a diffrence)

Thanks for all the instant help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)