# Datagrip local database is stuck in read only

Tags: mysql, readonly, datagrip

We're 2 people working with Mysql in Datagrip and both of us have the problem that when trying to apply changes to our local database after a simple SELECT statement it's read only: "This view is read-only".

It hasn't been a problem until 2 weeks ago.

In same tab we are able to apply changes to our test and production database.

We've tried everything that's been mentioned in this question:
[datagrip Cannot apply changes This table is read only. Cell editor changes cannot be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709655/datagrip-cannot-apply-changes-this-table-is-read-only-cell-editor-changes-canno)

We've also tried to reinstall mysql and datagrip. If we double click any table in the local database we can make changes that way, or through update statements.

Does anyone have any suggestions to what might be the problem? It's getting really painful.

Comment: Can you please try DataGrip 2017.3 EAP? https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/nextversion/

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve my issue either.

Comment: Seems that you have problems with resolve. Can you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: @MatMat Do you experience the issue in DataGrip 2023.1?