# Read only view in DataGrip

Tags: mongodb, datagrip

I have a local MongoDB instance that I am connecting to in DataGrip. When I open a collection and it loads in DataGrip, I try to edit a value in one of the fields and I am greeted with *This view is read-only*

I had a look at the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709655/datagrip-cannot-apply-changes-this-table-is-read-only-cell-editor-changes-canno) but I can't find the auto commit checkbox so I can't try it. If someone can maybe point out where that would be in DataGrip for MongoDB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can't edit values. But it's coming soon.

Follow the issues:

- [DBE-9645](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9645)
- [DBE-9375](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9375)